# Blackberry "fast" input

Tags: blackberry, input

A Blackberry game runs at 30 fps.  I want to be able to *poll* the keyboard for input at 30 fps, not merely "wait" for input events through overriding

```
public boolean keyChar( char key, int status, int time )
```

This is insanely slow and will never work.  how can I poll the blackberry for fast input?

Comment: Well, I'd like to read 30 inputs a second, but the simulator shows about 2 inputs a second or less using keyChar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you expecting the keyboard state to change 30 times a second?  Or do you just want to know the state of the keyboard 30 times a second?  I would guess that you are looking for the second, in which case I would just use keyDown and keyUp and store an array of booleans for which keys you care about being up or down.

Comment: Agree. This seems to be the most sensible solution.

Comment: Ah, a classic suggestion.  But the response time will still be lacking!  I guess there isn't a way to get __faster response__ input atm